# Get all info through one command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know when I start a bat file and have `pause` at the end it will stay open.
Then when pressing the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> the bat file ends, and the command prompt will be closed.

Also I know when we use `cmd /k` it will stay opened, and there is even a command prompt left to enter some bat file code.

Without `pause` or `cmd /k` there will be a new window opened and it closes itself.

What I really want to is to have a console window opened, and every time I run a bat file I want the output to be seen on the cmd that is already opened.

I like the way that I can see all the code that was running, without to having close the windows every time, and like it as if all the code will be seen in one opened cmd prompt.

edit: 2

first_file.bat

```
@echo first
call "C:\ProgramData\Cool\second_file.bat"
@echo thirth
```

second_file.bat

```
@echo second
```

Comment: Provided your batch scripts end with `Goto:Eof` or `Exit /B` and not `exit`, All you need to do is open a command prompt and run them directly from there. Using this approach, `cmd /k` is not required.

Comment: first of all thanks. i have updated the question with 2 bat files added.
i do not need exit /b or goto:Eof. the thing is the second bat file is using call. so it is no problem.
thing is when using start there will be a new window opend